# How do I define a smaller space in Math mode?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

[These are all the standard math mode spaces](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Spacing_in_math_mode) in Latex. The smallest one, defined by `\,`, has a length of 3 mu. My question is very simple: **can I define smaller spaces in math mode, for instance one of 1 or 2 mus?** If possible, how do I do so?

Thank you all very much in advance for your time.

Comment: `x \mkern 1mu x`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Could you please turn it into an answer, with a bit of an explanation, for me to accept it?

Comment: `\mskip1mu` too. If what you want is to make all of those `\,` smaller, you can do `\thinmuskip=2mu`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the math analogues of `\kern` (for fixed spaces) and `\hskip` (for stretchy space) are `\mkern` and `\mskip` which take `mu` units where a `mu` is 1/18 em

so you can do

```
$x \mkern 1mu x$
```

but it is rather rare to use explicit space rather than use the named spaces such as `\,` which is `\mkskip\thinmuskip`

`\thinmuskip` isn't a fixed length, it is given an initial value of

```
\thinmuskip=3mu
```

but if you are using a math font other than computer modern a slightly larger or smaller amount may be more suitable, so a global setting such as

```
%\thinmuskip=3mu
%\medmuskip=4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu
%\thickmuskip=5mu plus 5mu

\thinmuskip=2mu
\medmuskip=3mu plus 2mu minus 3mu
\thickmuskip=4mu plus 4mu
```

would give tighter spacing

Comment: Using XeLatex, I set \thinmuskip=1mu directly after defining \documentclass. I can change it to whatever I want, no change in the PDF.